# How are char * and string different in C++ ? (wrt the code in the description)

Tags: c++, string

Coming from C, I was always taught that char * and string are very similar to each other.
Here is a piece of code that I implemented using string and char * .

**The latter gives an error.**

> prog.cpp: In function 'char* foo()':
>
> prog.cpp:8:15: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant
>   to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>        char *bro="karan";

Why does the latter not work as intended?

The *string* one:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string foo()
{
    string bro="karan";
    return bro;
}

int main()
{
    cout << foo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The *char* *  one:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

char *foo()
{
    char *bro="karan";
    return bro;
}

int main()
{
    cout << foo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The latter gives an error." And we should just guess this error?

Comment: s/`string *foo()`/`string foo()`

Comment: I think you mean that the *first* code snippet gives errors. And those errors have nothing to do with the difference between `char*` and `std::string`.

Comment: sorry. I'll edit it asap.

Comment: @StoryTeller except for the lack of `const`.

Comment: @Quentin - Good point. I was tunnel-visioning on the whole `string` -> `string*` thing. Both samples are equally wrong.

Comment: question edited @StoryTeller

Comment: Warning is not an error.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao - The above is a warning only for legacy reasons. Strict compliance should be adhered to. It's not valid C++ code.

Comment: A string literal is really an array of constant characters. The type of e.g. `"karan"` is `const char [6]`. As all arrays it naturally decays to a pointer to its first element, which is of type `const char*`. And you can't simply convert away `const` in C++ without a special language-construct. I suggest you get [a good C++ beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as it should be explained in it.

Comment: @StoryTeller What I meant to point out was the difference between warning and an error. Code with warning will still compile and run whereas a code with error will fail to compile. In his case, the compiled code will run. Compliance and code validity is a difference story though

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao - No, not really. Turning on compliance options will make the above an error. The difference between an "error" and a "warning" when it's a compliance matter is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
char *bro="karan";
```

The `bro` variable is a `char*`. The string `"karan"` is a `const char[6]` data type, and will implicitly convert to `const char*`, which means "pointer to a constant value"

Your warning comes from the fact that on that line, you try to assign something that points to `const` data to something that points to non `const` data.

Here, `std::string` and `char*` differs from the fact that `std::string` has a constructor that takes a `const char*`, [see reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), allocate a char array internally, and make a copy of the string, while with the code with `char*` does not copy anything.